# How to stop 'CORS missing allow origin error' when deploying Express application using Serverless Component?

Tags: express, cors, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

When my React frontend calls my Typescript Express REST API (hosted on API Gateway using [Serverless Components](https://github.com/serverless-components/express)), I get the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://randomId.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/userLoginSignup' from origin 'https://www.tueshey.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

My app.ts CORS config is like this (for reference, [here](https://github.com/Siyer2/uni-connector/blob/main/backend/src/app.ts)'s my whole file):

```
...
const app = express();

// CORS
const allowlist = ['https://www.tueshey.com'];
const options: cors.CorsOptions = {
  origin: allowlist,
};
app.use(cors(options));
...
```

When I inspect the request locally, there is an OPTIONS request that returns first that includes the Allow Access Origin header but not when I deploy it. It is working correctly locally.

Answer (score 2):

you will have to enable CORS on API Gateway as well. When click on the resource endpoint on API Gateway, on actions there is Enable CORS. That will add Options method also for your resource. If you want some customization you will have to add OPTIONS method manually